# Does adding a block to Object.send pass it to the called method?

Tags: ruby

I just completed the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com), and neither the unit on calling methods using Object.send nor the Ruby documentation on the method provides any information on using blocks with the send method.  Will a block attached to the send method be passed to the method it calls, or will the block be lost?

Example:

```
foo.send(:a_method) { bar.another_method }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-send) is a bit unclear on this:

> **send(symbol [, args...]) → obj**
>
> Invokes the method identified by *symbol*, passing it any arguments specified.

But note the *any arguments specified* part. The block that you give to a method is really a funny type of implicit argument so that you can do things like:

```
def m(&b)
  @a.each(&b)
end
m { |e| puts e }
```

to pass the block around as a Proc instance. However, you can also do this:

```
def m
  yield
end
m { puts 'pancakes' }
```

so the block is special as far as the argument list is concerned but the block still behaves as an argument even if it is sometimes implicit.

Given the above "block is sort of an argument" rambling and the importance of blocks in Ruby, it would be reasonable for `send` to pass the block through. You can also try it but you have to careful about accidental and undocumented behavior with the "try it" approach:

```
class C
  def m
    yield
  end
end
o = C.new
o.send(:m) { puts 'pancakes' }
# "pancakes" comes out
```

Answer (score 16):

Yes. Consider the following:

```
class A
  def explicit(&b); b; end
  def implicit; yield "hello"; end
end

>> A.new.send(:explicit) { }
=> #<Proc:0x0000000000000000@(irb):19>
>> A.new.send(:implicit) { |greeting| puts greeting }
hello
=> nil
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will. Inside the method you can check it with `block_given?` and call the block with `yield`

#### Code

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "before yield"
    yield if block_given?
    puts "after yield"
  end
end

f = Foo.new
f.send(:bar)
puts ""
f.send(:bar) { puts "yield"}
```

#### Output

```
before yield
after yield

before yield
yield
after yield
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Yes, the `send` method will pass the closure to the method it calls.

Under the hood, a closure supplied to a method call implicitly gets passed to the method as an additional argument (albeit a special one). You can use the closure explicitly with `call` ...

```
> def do_it(&block)
>   block.call
> end
 => :do_it 

> do_it { puts 'apples' }
apples
 => nil
```

... or implicitly with `yield`.

```
> def do_it_with_yield
>   yield if block_given?
> end
 => :do_it_with_yield

> do_it_with_yield { puts 'bananas' }
bananas
 => nil
```

You can pass closures to any method, including `:send`, `:public_send`, etc., though it is up to the method called to use the closure or not.

In the case of `send` et al, they dutifully pass the closure along as we would hope and expect.

```
> self.public_send(:do_it) { puts 'cherries' }
cherries
 => nil

> self.send(:do_it_with_yield) { puts 'dates' }
dates
 => nil
```

This is important when implementing the `method_missing` method, for example.

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  puts "Delegating #{method_name} to api handler"
  my_api_handler.send(method_name, *args, &block)
end
```

References:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-ruby-closures
- https://medium.com/rubycademy/the-yield-keyword-603a850b8921
- https://www.leighhalliday.com/ruby-metaprogramming-method-missing